# I am not able to open the Django admin file

Tags: django-admin

Whenever I start a new Django project using:

```sh
(virtual) C:\myDjangoProject>python django_admin.py startproject DjgoProject
```

I receive the following error:

> python: can't open file 'django_admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Any guidance please?

Comment: Welcome. I've formatted your question so it's a bit easier to read. Take a look at the changes, as they'll help you format questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a virtual environment (which it looks like you have) and then run:

```
pip install django
```

Then you shouldn't need to run django-admin directly like that, you can just do the following:

```
django-admin startproject DjgoProject
```